# Emacs: replace regexp with per-match prompt

Tags: regex, emacs

Emacs 23.3 is said to allow prompting part of the replacement string on each match, via the `\?` syntax.

The string should be prompted in the mini-buffer.

This feature is described here:
http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexp-Replace.html

I tried the simple replacement `(query-replace-regexp "^" "\\?")` with Emacs 23.3 on Windows, but I get a "Invalid use of `\' in replacement text" error.

Any idea on how I should use this feature ?

Note: I could use `\,(read-from-minibuffer "? ")` instead but doing so prompts for a string before highlighting the match.

I don't think it matters, but my version of Emacs is the following: GNU Emacs 23.3.1 (i386-mingw-nt6.1.7601).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a feature of `replace-regexp`, not `query-replace-regexp`. (Didn't know about this feature; thanks for highlighting it!)

Comment: In `query-replace-regexp` you can always press `e` to edit the replacement text.

Comment: That great ! That is in fact the behavior I was looking for.